# How would I determine if I'm on the 'edge' of a 2D array in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So lets say that I have a 5x5 matrix 2D array and I have to determine if I am on the "edge" of the array. As in, if I am along the "border" of the array at any point, I have reached the edge and need to end the while loop that calls on a -- what i'm assuming will be a method -- that determines this. How would I go about with this scenario?

Comment: Test if the indices are one off from any side.

Comment: Help me, I'm stuck in the Matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if the indices are one off from any side.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) 
    {
        if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == matrix.length - 1 || j == matrix[i].length - 1)
        {
            System.out.printf("On [%d, %d] is on the border.", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```